# SQL Query for Book Search, Find near words

Tags: sql

I have a table with all word positions in a book.

the table is like this:

```
 Word  PageNo  Position
----------------------
   A     1       10
   A     1       30
   A     1       50
   A     2       38
   B     1       14
   B     1       32
   B     2       40
   B     2       41
   B     2       50
   C     1       30
   D     2       12
```

I want to find the rows where words A and B that are near each other.

the answer is:

```
 Word  PageNo  Position
----------------------
   A     1       10
   B     1       14
   A     1       30
   B     1       32
   A     2       38
   B     2       40
   B     2       41
```

for example row (A,1,50) is wrong because there is no B near it.

I wrote this query:

```
select * from
(
    SELECT *, (PageNo * 100) + Position as k FROM t where t.Word = "A"
) a
inner join
(
    SELECT *, (PageNo * 100) + Position as k FROM t where t.Word = "B"
) b on abs(a.k - b.k) < 10
```

I used (p * 100) + Po to find the real position in book
and I want the distance between words to be lower than 10 chars.

this works but it gives me this:

```
word    pageno  position    k   word2   pageno2 position2    k2
----------------------------------------------------------------
 A        1        10      110   B         1       14       114
 A        1        30      130   B         1       32       132
 A        2        38      238   B         2       40       240
 A        2        38      238   B         2       41       241
```

It has eight columns because of join statement.
I want to have A positions union B positions under it.

Is there any other suggestions for it?

Comment: my rdbms doesnt matter, I want ANSI SQL

Comment: is there 100 postion by page? why is `(PageNo * 100)` there is `page = 0` ??

Comment: consider pageno between 1 and 10 and positions between 1 and 99

Comment: Why is word `D` on page `12` not present in your sample output?  And what constitutes "near" ?

Comment: I want only A and B those are near each other

Comment: if you consider position between 1 and 99 there will a gap on the page change, and you should change to `(page * 99)`

Comment: Your example query is **not** ANSI SQL. `"B"` is a column name not a string constant in SQL. So your DBMS _does_ matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will convert your result to the format you need:

```
;with cte 
AS
(
select a.word worda
, b.word wordb
, a.PageNo pagenoa
, b.PageNo pagenob
, a.Position pa
, b.Position pb from 
(
    SELECT word, pageno, position, (PageNo * 100) + Position as k FROM book where Word = 'A'
) a
inner join
(
    SELECT word, pageno, position, (PageNo * 100) + Position as k FROM book where Word = 'B'
) b on abs(a.k - b.k) < 10
)
select worda, pagenoa, pa from cte where cte.worda = 'A'
UNION
select wordb, pagenob, pb from cte where cte.wordb = 'B'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Distinct  a.word,    a.pageno,   a.position 
from t as a
join t as b
  ON abs((a.PageNo * 100) + a.Position - (b.PageNo * 100) + b.Position) < 10
 AND (   (a.Word = 'A' and b.Word = 'B')
      OR (a.Word = 'B' and b.Word = 'A')
     )
```

maybe you can use this for last condition

```
AND ( a.Word + b.Word IN ( 'AB', 'BA' ))
```

Comment: `a.Word + b.Word IN ( "AB", "BA")` is nt ANSI SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you mean the `a.Word + b.Word` or `IN ( "AB", "BA")` part?

Comment: Both. In SQL String are concatenated with `||` and double quotes denote column names not string constants. You query would be correct ANSI SQL _if_ (and only if) `word` was a numeric column and the table had two _columns_ named `AB` and `BA`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok I fix the string I was just copy paste. But the `+ ` is also the string concatenation on MSQL. btw I search the [ANSI](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)  page 20 and say `<concatenation operator> is an operator, |, ` download pdf for 2011 and I didnt find the operator. Where you check the ansi standard?

Comment: Search for `<concatenation operator> ::= ` on that page.